# What's wrong with javaScript's addition?

Tags: javascript

I am trying this simple addition in Javascript could someone please let me know why is it giving NaN as a result ?

```
function add(a,b,c)
{
 z= a+b+c;
 console.log(z);
 }

 add(10+10+10);
```

Answer (score 2):

You define the function to accept three arguments and you are passing only one argument. As a result, the values of `b` and `c` are `undefined` in the function and adding `undefined` to a number results in `NaN`. Try this instead:

```
add(10, 10, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Add` function expects 3 parameters. `a`, `b` and `c`. What you are doing now is passing an expression `10+10+10` which is not a valid number.
Try as following

```
function add(a,b,c)
{
 z= a+b+c;
 console.log(z);
}

add(10,10,10);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass your arguments separately:

```
add(10, 10, 10);
```

---

The problem is that you've added the numbers before passing them to your function:

```
add(10+10+10);
```

adds together 10, 10 and 10, then passes it to the function, so really your code is:

```
function add(a,b,c) {
  z= a+b+c;
  console.log(z);
}

add(30);
```

Which will not work, because your function expects 3 arguments and only gets 1.

```
function add(a,b,c) {
  // a is 30, b and c are both undefined
  z= a+b+c;
  console.log(z);
}
```